# Недопустимое применение 'sizeof' к типу функции [-Wpointer-arith]

Tags: c++

Написал функцию, возвращающую нужное количество байт для выравнивания полей с данным количеством битов. Здесь я возвращаю размер типа:

```
template < size_t Number_of_bits >
size_t   aligning_fields() { return sizeof(std::bitset<Number_of_bits>); }
```

В другой функции получаю размер обьекта этого типа, и делаю это двумя способами, которые отличаются друг от друга только парой скобок:

```
template < size_t N >
size_t flaw(bool b) {
return b ? sizeof((std::bitset<N>())) : sizeof(std::bitset<N>());
}
```

И тут не смог понять предупреждение компилятора, который видите в заголовке вопроса. Можете сказать: "Не пиши так..." Но меня интересует **ответ на вопрос**: "В чем причина такого поведения?".

Дальше продолжил эксперимент, чтобы выяснить что к чему:

```
int main()
{  
    cout << aligning_fields<33>() <<endl // 8 bayts
         <<flaw<33>(true) <<endl          // 8
        <<flaw<33>(false);                // 1
    return 0;
}
```

Где возник **второй вопрос**: что возвращает flaw<33>(false)?

Comment: @Vadizar, спасибо за правку, я  заметил еще одну  ошибку в тексте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы столкнулись с тем, что называется [«Most vexing parse»](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), Ваш код (его `false` часть) для компилятора является применением `sizeof` к **функции**, которая возвращает `std::bitset<N>` и не имеет аргументов. Но согласно стандарту, применять `sizeof` к функциям запрещено, поэтому Вы и видите предупреждение. Правда, там должно быть не предупреждение, а ошибка, поэтому gcc поступает плохо, выдавая лишь предупреждение.

В первом же случае (`true` часть), Вы используете типичную форму записи, которую использовали (до C++11), чтобы убедить компилятор, что это не функция, а создание объекта. Сейчас же в этом нет нужды, т.к. можно (и нужно!) использовать синтаксис с фигурными скобками:

```
return b ? sizeof((std::bitset<N>{})) : sizeof(std::bitset<N>{});
```

Но в таком виде эти записи дают идентичный результат и Ваша функция не нужна.

Comment: хороший ответ  с дополнительной информацией

Answer (score 1):

В первом случае  `(flaw<33>(true))`, вы получаете размер битсета, потому что вы запрашиваете у sizeof размер объекта, который сгенерирует конструктор битсета. У вас написано - вызови конструктор, результат положи в скобочки, измерь размер, уничтожь результат.

Во втором случае, вы просто получаете случайную фигню, которую сгенерировал компилятор в качестве реакции на барахло. В полном соответствии с великим принципом ИТ GIGO = Garbage In - Garbage Out

Вы фактически спрашиваете у `sizeof` - "а какой размер конструктора у битсета", а он справедливо пишет в вам warning "Чо?!" и выдает единицу, удивляясь вашей глупости.

Чтобы узнать размер битсета, не нужно писать к нему скобочки, наличие скобочек говорит компилятору, что вы хотите дернуть конструктор.

Comment: вы наверное согласны, что SO является официальным сайтом.  Вы в официальном сайте  заявляете о чей то глупости, когда вам задают вопрос. Еслиб все все знали бы, то и этого сайта не существовало бы.  Вы же не станете утверждать, что вы знаете абсолютно все и никогда не задавали вопросов. Или вы себя тоже считаете глупым?...

Comment: Официальный сайт - это сайт, на котором вам официально  отвечают официальные сотрудники официальной компании, официально получая за это официальную зарплату. 

Здесь же вам отвечают обычные живые люди, иногда склонные к иронии и к самоиронии. В данном случае, перед очередным запутанным случаем интересного крючкотворства на C++. Обратите внимание, что утверждение о глупости автора программы в моем ответе исходит от лица компилятора, а не от моего собственного.

Comment: Компилятор вежливо предупреждает,  но смысль моих слов  не в том, что вы меня задели чем то, а втом, чтоб вы старались быть вежливее.  Отвечайте на вопросы так, чтоб люди свободно задавали новые вопросы, не  опасаясь  грубостей.   Я лично ,  иногда задаю вопрос, даже когда знаю ответ, потому что ответы на мои вопросы помогут другим,  плюс добавится количество вопросов и ответов, что обеспечивает живучесть сайта...

Comment: Я свой стиль общения менять не намерен. Либо я пишу так, как пишу всегда, то есть с перцем, иронией и постмодернистскими отсылками куда угодно, либо меня с данного сайта удаляют усилиями кровавой администрации. Средства для этого у всех есть - слив репутации, ковровые жалобы, бан и так далее. Я имею право писать что хочу и как хочу, сообщество имеет право меня выгнать. Свобода слова как она есть.